# How to manipulate multi-value string parameters for a SQL Command in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I have a Crystal Report based on a SQL Command that, in part, consists of procedure names. What I'm trying to do is add a multi-value string parameter to the SQL Command such that the end users can enter partial procedure names and the report will return only those relevant procedures that string match.

For example, a user should be able to enter "%KNEE%" and "%HIP%" into the parameter and return all procedures that contain the words "KNEE" and "HIP". The problem is that I can't figure out how to manipulate the parameter value in the SQL to accomplish this. I've done this before with a report parameter (as opposed to a SQL Command parameter) by simply adding the line `{table.procedure_name} like {?name match parameter}` to the record selection formula, but taking the same approach in the SQL Command gets me an "ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis" error.

Any suggestions on how I can manipulate the multi-value string parameter to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont like to post this as an answer because I don't care for the solution however it is the only way I have found to work around this. 
I have had to instruct users to enter '%KNEE%','%HIP%','%ETC%' at the parameter prompt. Then the {table.procedure_name} like {?name match parameter} should work in your SQL. Not optimal, especially for your scenario with the %. I would love to hear someone provide a better solution because I have wrestled with this many times.

Comment: Another possibility would be if there are only a few possible entries provide multiple parameters to the user and concatenate those each surrounded by " and use that result after the LIKE

Comment: This is close to what I did. I ended up just passing a single value parameter to a `regex_like()` and giving the user complete control over string matching with a regular expression. I don't expect them to get very fancy with it, but it gives me the option of adding complex patterns to the parameter drop-down menu for them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

```
SELECT column0
FROM   table0
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT trim('%' || x.column_value.extract('e/text()') || '%') SEARCH
    FROM  ( SELECT 'arm,knee' options FROM dual ) t,
    TABLE (xmlsequence(xmltype('<e><e>' || replace(t.options,',','</e><e>')|| '</e></e>').extract('e/e'))) x

) v ON column0 LIKE v.search
```

Use Oracle's XML functionality to convert a comma-delimited string to an equivalent number of rows, wrapping each clause with `%%`.  Then join those rows to the desired table.

To use with CR, create a single-value, string parameter and add it to the code:

```
...
FROM  ( SELECT '{?search_param}' options FROM dual ) t,
...
```